# How to get the neighbor's nodes of a path in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a path and I want to get the nodes that connected to this path by some edges. I wrote this qwery and it's not working properly:

```
match p=(a)-[:example*]->(c) where length(p) = 5 
with p
match (u)-[r:example2]-> p return u,p,r
```

I want to get all that nodes 'u'.
can you tell me please what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your query as a source code with the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the nodes of the path using the [`nodes()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-nodes) function, [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-unwind) the list and then perform the match. You might want to [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#aggregation-collect) the results for each node `a`.

```
match p=(a)-[:example*]->(c)
where length(p) = 5
with a, nodes(p) as pathNodes
unwind pathNodes as pathNode
match (u)-[r:example2]->(pathNode)
return a, collect([u, pathNode])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but how do I get all the nodes, not only the n's place of the path?(p[n])

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Note that you might only want to collect `u` or `pathNode` nodes, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! (I needed only the count of u)

Comment: what is u in the fifth line ?

Comment: `u` is a new variable introduced on that line. The `MATCH` clause in Cypher allows you to introduce new variables (unlike the `WHERE` clause which only allows using existing variables).